# SQL calculation with joined datasets

Tags: sql, join, calculation

I am new to SQL and I've been working on a dataset where I wanted to join two datasets and calculate their variance:

```
SELECT 
    dataset_1.column_1,
    SUM(dataset_1.column2) AS column_2,
    SUM(dataset_2.column3) AS column3,
    column_2 - column_3 AS Variance
FROM 
    source_data.dataset1 AS dataset_1
JOIN
    source_data.dataset2 AS dataset_2
    ON dataset_1.column_1 = dataset_2.column_1
GROUP BY 
    dataset_1.column_1
ORDER BY
    dataset_1.column_1
```

There was an error in the row:

```
 column_2 - column_3 AS Variance
```

saying it does not recognize column_2.
How do I resolve to show another column for variance?

Comment: Since `column_2` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause, it needs to be aggregated. The same can be said about `column_3`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    dataset_1.column_1,
    SUM(dataset_1.column2) AS column_2,
    SUM(dataset_2.column3) AS column3,
    SUM(dataset_1.column2) - SUM(dataset_2.column3 AS Variance
FROM 
    source_data.dataset1 AS dataset_1
JOIN
    source_data.dataset2 AS dataset_2
    ON dataset_1.column_1 = dataset_2.column_1
GROUP BY 
    dataset_1.column_1
ORDER BY
    dataset_1.column_1
```

Annoyingly, you cannot use the alias for the calculations in your select statement.